# Blazor error Could not find NativeFileReference

Tags: blazor

I am watching [this Steve Sanderson's Video titled ***New Blazor WebAssembly capabilities in .NET 6***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os).

I Cloned [the git hub repo](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital) and tried to build [the BlazeOrbital solution inside of it](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/tree/main/BlazeOrbital).

I am getting the following errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Could not find NativeFileReference
> ..\rustqr\target\wasm32-unknown-emscripten\debug\librustqr.a  BlazeOrbital.ManufacturingHub   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\6.0.1\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets    228
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MC3066  The type reference cannot find a public type named
> 'Inventory'. Line 12 Position
> 51.   BlazeOrbital.Accounting E:\Vivek\Trials\WebApps\Blazor\BlazeOrbital\BlazeOrbital\Accounting\Inventory.xaml  12

Certainly I am missing something here as I am new to Blazor.

Can someone please nudge me whats happening here?

When I look at Solution Explorer, I see a missing file librustqr.dll

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer with missing librustqr.dll]

Where do I get that from, or how do I build that? [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) is Greek and Latin to me, so please help.

But the other solution [Satellite Simulator](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/tree/main/SatelliteSimulator) runs fine.

[image: Satellite Simulator in Action]

## Update

I followed the steps @Janus1986. I downloaded the rustup-init.exe as mentioned. Also installed C++ Build tools. Then installed [emscripten](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/emscripten)

[image: Visual Studio 2022 C++ Build Tools]

Then I ran cargo build from the [this rustqr folder](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/tree/main/BlazeOrbital/rustqr).

Now I get this error.

> warning: unused manifest key: build
> Compiling bmp-monochrome v1.0.0
> error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
> |
> = note: the `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` target may not be installed
> = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-emscripten`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `bmp-monochrome` due to previous error

[image: cargo build error for rustqr]

:(

Stuck.

Can someone elaborate what steps are need to get this up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem, the repository don't have all libraries you have tou build it, it's a simple rust library.
You'll have to install rust
https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe
then emscripten (I installed it from chocolatey)
https://chocolatey.org/install

```
choco install emscripten
```

then go to the rust folder to build the libs

```
cargo build
```

change the target to x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

```
rustup update
rustup install x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

and change the
inside config.toml:

```
[build]
target = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
```

and change in cargo.toml

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

cargo build
```

you should have all libraries

Comment: Can you please look at my update? I getting a new error.

Comment: have you tryed to launch
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-emscripten

Comment: No..Any tutorial that you can point to for that.

Comment: my docs
https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html